# Mocking with Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ocmock

Consider the following class named **SomeClass** written in **Swift**:

```
@objc class SomeClass: NSObject
{
    var shouldCallBar = false

    func foo()
    {
        if (shouldCallBar == true)
        {
            bar()
        }
    }

    func bar()
    {
    }
}
```

For testing the above class **foo()** method (and similar scenarios mostly written in Objective-C) I was using OCMock like:

```
- (void) testFooBarShouldBeCalledWhenShouldCallBarIsTrue
{
    SomeClass * someClass = [SomeClass new];

    // Create mocks.
    id mockSomeClass = OCMPartialMock(someClass);

    // Expect.
    [[mockSomeClass expect] bar];

    // Stub.
    someClass.shouldCallBar = YES;

    // Run code under test.
    [someClass foo];

    // Verify.
    [mockSomeClass verify];

    // Stop mocking.
    [mockSomeClass stopMocking];
}
```

But above test fails with Swift code as [OCMock won't works well with Swift](http://ocmock.org/swift/).

So I am considering something like entirely in Swift:

```
class SomeClassTests: XCTestCase
{
    class MockSomeClass: SomeClass
    {
        var isBarCalled = false

        override func bar()
        {
            isBarCalled = true
        }
    }

    func testBarShouldBeCalledWhenTrue()
    {
        let someClass = MockSomeClass()
        someClass.shouldCallBar = true

        someClass.foo()

        XCTAssertTrue(someClass.isBarCalled == true)
    }
}
```

Note here I am subclassing the original class under test and overriding the **bar()**. I am not at all touching the **foo()** implementation.

But the downside is I am using **MockSomeClass** instance to test **foo()** of **SomeClass**. This is something I don't like and [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520332/ocmverify-expect-in-swift).

Is there any better solution to the problem above?

Notes:

- I am not talking about Dependency Injection here. Dependency Injection is entirely different approach.
- I face these kind of issues when testing UI code in UIViewController.
- I have thought of Protocol based programming but was not able to come up with solution to problem above.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as primarily opinion based.  You have presented us with a working solution.  You haven't sufficiently explained why it's not good enough for your needs.  You're looking for a generic "better" and haven't really outlined *any* criteria for what counts as better.  Here's some [recommended reading](http://importblogkit.com/2016/03/how-to-ask-a-good-stack-overflow-question/)...

Comment: ... and by the way.... there are several problems with how you've implemented, but this general pattern is the correct way, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to test that one method (`foo`) does or does not call another method (`bar`). The `foo` method is the one under test, and the `bar` method is, in the wider sense, a dependent component.

If the invocation of `bar` has lasting side effects, you could get away with testing that the side effect is/isn't present, maybe by querying a property or similar. In that case you don't need mocks or similar.

If there are no side effects then you must substitute the dependency. To do so you need a *seam* at which you place code that can tell the test whether the method has been invoked or not. For that, I can only see the two options that Jon already discussed in the [question you refer to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520332/ocmverify-expect-in-swift).

You either put the two methods into separate classes, in which case the class boundary is the seam. Using a protocol, or just an informal convention, you can then completely replace the class that implements `bar`. Dependency injection comes in handy here.

If the two methods must stay in the same class then you have to use a subclass boundary as a seam, i.e. you use the fact that you can override methods and implement a [test-specific sublass](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test-Specific%20Subclass.html). It's easiest when you can use a mock framework. If that's not an option you have to write the code yourself, much like what you describe in your question.